# Difference between different form action attribute

Tags: java, html, servlets

Can any one tell in following cases where the request will be submitted at web application running at tomcat server:

```
<form action="register.abc">
<form action="/register.abc">
<form action="/Lab3/register.abc"> //Labx is the webproject name
```

Comment: action="xyz" ..here xyz is the place( servlet/html page/image or any other file you want to reach on your web site directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you start with "/" means that start from your root path. without "/" the url is based on you current local on your web site. For example.

You are here localhost:8080/Labx/mypage.html

```
<form action="register.abc"> // == localhost:8080/Labx/register.abc
<form action="/register.abc"> // == localhost:8080/register.abc
<form action="/Lab3/register.abc"> //== localhost:8080/Lab3/register.abc
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case 'register.abc' will be searched in the same directory where the page that contains it is located.

In the second and third cases the absolute path is provided, so it will be searched in the context of your website regardless where the calling page is, e.g.

```
http://host:port/Lab3/register.abc
```